# Amazon SNS Mobile Push - APNS app registration

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I have problem setting up my first Amazon SNS mobile push application.

I followed the [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePushPrereq.html) Amazon provided to get all required files: Apple Push Notification SSL, Application Private Key and Device token.

Then I followed the guide to register the app. I went to the AWS SNS console and clicked on "add a new app", then I chose APNS_SANDBOX, used the .p12 file and tried to load credentials from the file, but got the following error

"File type is not supported or file has been corrupted"

I tried to find relative information online but couldn't get any. Any idea how I could fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

AWS wants your file to be .pem file, convert .p12 to .pem Normally, I just copy the certificate and keys and just paste them in the box on the dashboard though.

Answer (score 1):

In the AWS SNS "Create Platform Application" screen I successfully used a .p12 file, which was exported key file.

The enter password field is for entering the password the .p12 was encrypted.

After entering the password pressing the "Load Credentials from file" button the fields for the certificate and private key were filled in.

Comment: I can't emphasize enough how important your last paragraph is. The Amazon docs don't seem to exaplain that in any way.